# simple timestamp for SMS on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sms

I am thinking this is an easy question, because I know how to do it in iChat for the computer.

But for an iPhone, SMS messages are shown as a speech bubble in a conversation with someone. Aside from the timestamp banner that appears before a message that is a long time after previous messages in an SMS conversation, how can I get a timestamp (or the time sent) of an SMS message?

Comment: Are you open to solutions that sync to a computer or does it need to be constrained to software that runs on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

if your iPhone is jailbroken you can download [this](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=xmessagesDp) tweak (xMessages
) for free from the cydia store

Comment: but my iPhone is not jailbroken... can I get the timestamp info a different way?

Comment: Well. You can't. But it's free and legal to jailbreak your phone

Comment: But jailbreaking the iPhone automatically forfeits any support and VOIDS AppleCare which in my opinion isn't worth jailbreaking. Are there any other possible ways to have SMS timestamps w/o jailbreaking?

Comment: a) you can always restore and get back apple warranty. And there's isn't no other way.